# Disable back and forward pages shortcuts on Chrome (and others browsers)

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I have a shortcut that run a URL as a APP in Chrome (without navbar), but the shortcuts still works.

Example: C:[...]\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app=http://google.com

Comment: Maybe you need to take control of the key bindings using JavaScript, I think.

Comment: @DeveshKhandelwal That will only work with javascript enabled. My people disable it ...